# Probability of a 1 in a million event 4 times in a population of 15K?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to get to grips with the basics of probability so have been looking out for news articles or comments where I can try to apply my learnings.

I was reading [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19757225) post concerning the incidence of cancel in a small USA town. I did not read the article they are actually discussing on that thread but I did pick up this comment and wanted to use it to test my knowledge:

> **Four one in a million events in 15k inhabitants.** Yes in any ranked
>   list of stochastic outcomes there must be a highest scorer and a
>   lowest scorer, but in case of Wayland GA it's still off the charts.
>   With these diseases for any given town in the US you'd expect 0 or 1,
>   hardly ever 2, if independently distributed.

Considering only the text highlighted in bold, I attempted to infer the probability and am unsure of my conclusion:

If the probability of the event really is 1 in a million and we assume the events are independent, then is the probability of this occurring $(1/1000000)^4$ = $\frac{1}{1000000000000000000000000}$ ?

Or, is it 1 in a million times 4 = 1/250000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, assuming independence, the number of occurrences is a binomial random variable $X$ with $n=15000$ and $p=1/1000000$. Thus the probability of exactly four occurrences is
$$\binom{n}{4}p^4(1-p)^{n-4}.$$ 
However, you should instead ask for the probability of *at least* $4$ occurrences. This is given by:
\begin{align*}
P(X \geq 4) &= 1-P(X \leq 3)\\
&=1-(P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3))\\
&=1-\left(\binom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^n + \binom{n}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}+\binom{n}{3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}\right).
\end{align*}
The numbers get really big, but this works out to about $2\times 10^{-9}$. Notice that even the probability of zero occurrences is:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{1000000}\right)^{15000} \approx 0.985$$
so there is a $98.5\%$ chance that no one gets cancer, assuming independence.

Answer (score 1):

If the incidents were independent, then we'd expect them to follow a  [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  In that case the probability of seeing exactly $4$ incidents would be $$\binom {15000}4\times \left(\frac 1{10^6}\right)^4\times \left(\frac {10^6-1}{10^6}\right)^{14996}\approx 2.077\times 10^{-9}$$

And the probability of seeing at least $4$ incidents would be $$1-\sum_{i=0}^3\binom {15000}i\times \left(\frac 1{10^6}\right)^i\times \left(\frac {10^6-1}{10^6}\right)^{15000-i}\approx 2.083\times 10^{-9}$$

Thus, a very low probability indeed.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be $15000 \choose 4$?

Comment: @雨が好きな人 Indeed it should.  I'll edit accordingly.